# Create hierarchical data (Org Chart)on excel automatically

Tags: excel, hierarchy, orgchart

Pulling data from the database to excel and trying to create a hierarchy with the Roles and Manager columns.
First I do a pivot table to give me the count of employees  under each role.
Eg: 
CEO 2
VP 10
GM 10
etc . 
I am trying to get this data as a hierarchy on excel automatically without manually entering the values.
EG:
Pivot table gives:
[image]

and this is hierarchy chart: 
[image]

Trying to get the out put as :
[image]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I was wondering if there is a way to create a hierarchy chart automatically on excel with the Roles & Managers columns imported to the excel sheet.

Comment: Yes, there is a way - you need to be more specific with what your issue is. What have you tried so far? What is your sample data like? What is your expected outcome? Your question is far too broad for anyone here to help you at the moment.

Comment: Updated it above.

Comment: What are `Emp1`, `Emp2`, and `Emp3` and where are they in your sample data? Are these the only roles that can exist? Could there be an `Emp10`?

Comment: They are employees under VP and so on. This is just a sample to get an idea of how i am trying to get the data. There can be more sub values.

Comment: So how is the program supposed to know which role is a subset of who? How is your pivot table organized?

Answer (score -1):

BALKANGraph developer evangelist here

With OrgChart JS you can achieve requested functionality

```
var chart = new OrgChart(document.getElementById("tree"), {
        nodeBinding: {
            field_0: "name"
        },
        menu: {
            csv: {
                text: "Export CSV"
            },
            importCSV: {
                text: "Import CSV",
                onClick: upload,
                icon: BALKANGraph.icon.csv(24, 24, "#7A7A7A")
            }
        },
        nodes: nodes
    });
```

The implementation requires server side code.
[Here](https://github.com/BALKANGraph/OrgChart.ImportFormCSV) is a demo on GitHub.